# nvidia graphic drivers using VMware Fusion on a macbook pro

Tags: windows-7, drivers, macbook-pro, vmware-fusion, nvidia-graphics-card

I have a macbook pro retina with a nvidia gt 650m video card.

I use VMware Fusion and i want to update the drivers. 
I downloaded 320.18-notebook-win8-win7-64bit-international-whql.exe

When i try to run the installer i get this error:

[image: installer error]

I did a lot of searching, the closest i came is this:
http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1159573

I'm not using bootcamp but that probably doesn't matter for the solution.
Could it work? And more important, could it do any damage?

Or does someone know a better way?

Answer (score 1):

The point of using a virtual machine is to present a virtual machine (disks, cpu, ram, USB and video) to the guest os.

That means there is a virtual video card for the guest OS ... and VmWare provided a driver for that card.

So .. from within the guest-os, there is indeed no NVidia card present..

Comment: Bootcamp is not a virtual machine (as I assume you know) .. but, yes, **you can use VmWare Fusion to start your Bootcamp partition from within OS X**. I've been doing that for some time...